# "For each group of results fullfilling condition X, select only result with smallest column value A"

Tags: select

I have a table with data and dates like so:

```
DECLARE @p TABLE (P_key int, P_Data char(1), P_ValidUntil datetime)

INSERT @p VALUES (20, 'T', '2003-02-28')
INSERT @p VALUES (21, 'U', '2005-05-31')
INSERT @p VALUES (30, 'V', '2006-09-30')
INSERT @p VALUES (30, 'W', '2008-04-30')
INSERT @p VALUES (31, 'X', '2007-06-30')
INSERT @p VALUES (32, 'Y', '2005-01-31')
INSERT @p VALUES (32, 'Z', '2007-06-30')
INSERT @p VALUES (33, 'A', '2005-06-30')
```

Given: qKey (only multiples of 10), qDate

Find: All entries that match qKey in the first digit and have a date larger then qDate. Return only one result per P_key (the one with the next higher P_ValidUntil to qDate).

The current solution is:

```
DECLARE @qKey AS int;
DECLARE @qDate AS datetime;

SET @qKey=30;
SET @qDate='2006-01-01';

SELECT * FROM @p WHERE
@qKey = (P_Key/10)*10
AND @qDate <= P_ValidUntil
```

which returns:

```
30    V    2006-09-30 00:00:00.000
30    W    2008-04-30 00:00:00.000
31    X    2007-06-30 00:00:00.000
32    Z    2007-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

This is basically correct, except that there are two entries for 30 (both are bigger than @qDate). I only want the smallest date of these multiple hits in the result:

```
30    V    2006-09-30 00:00:00.000
31    X    2007-06-30 00:00:00.000
32    Z    2007-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first fix would be:

```
SELECT p2.*
from @p p2
JOIN (
    SELECT min(p_validUntil) Min_P_ValidUntil, P_Key
    FROM @p p
    WHERE @qKey = (P_Key/10)*10
    AND @qDate <= P_ValidUntil
    group BY P_Key
) p3 ON p3.Min_P_ValidUntil = p2.P_ValidUntil AND p3.P_Key = p2.P_Key
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Window function

```
SELECT
    P_Key, P_Data, P_ValidUntil
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P_Key ORDER BY P_ValidUntil) AS rn
    FROM
        @p
    WHERE
       P_Key / @qKey = 1 AND @qDate <= P_ValidUntil
    ) p2
WHERE
   rn = 1
```

FYI: both techniques used in the 2 answers are quite common because it's a common problem. Examples here in this DBA-SE question: [How to get the MAX row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row/1004#1004)

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link. Unfortunately I find it very hard to search for DB-Related questions, unlike for coding questions. Usually I create my DB-schemas in a way that simple SQL is enough to solve my problems.

Comment: @B3ret: it was really was FYI, not a criticism. The same Q pops up on StackOverflow quite often