# How do I group results in batches of consecutive rows with the same 'module'

Tags: oracle

I'm looking for a seemingly very simple SELECT.

I have a logging table LOGGING of which three columns are of interest to me: MODULE (text), PDATE (date), PTEXT (text).

Actually, I care only about the first two columns, i.e. which module has been called at all (which is the name of a procedure in a PL/SQL package). The date I only need for ordering (ASC) the result, and one could also use the ID column for the same purpose, which is an auto-incremented integer value (Oracle: sequence.nextval).

Since the logging produces waaaaayyyyy too much data, tens to hundreds of PTEXT entries for a single MODULE, I would like to condense the MODULE rows, which seems to call for a simple GROUP BY.

Maybe this illustrates the issue:

I start with the inner query below, which gives me the correct sequence of "module" calls, but does not aggregate them (example 1 above). So my idea was okay, I get the correct result in the correct order - so if I now select just the one column I'm interested in and use "group by" on this *ordered*(!) data I should get what I want - but adding the "group by" below gives me a COMPLETELY different order. Apparently my knowledge about what "group by" does is inadequate.

```
SELECT module FROM
(
  SELECT module, pdate FROM logging
  ORDER BY pdate asc
)
--GROUP BY module
```

Result without "GROUP BY" (first 12 lines):

```
set_option_value
set_option_value
set_option_value
set_option_value
get_rights_usecase
get_rights_usecase
get_rights_usecase
get_rights_usecase
get_rights_usecase
get_rights_usecase
get_fun_AppOptionsSingleVal
get_rights_usecase
...
```

Result incl. "GROUP BY":

```
get_fun_AppOptionsSingleVal
get_option_value
get_parameter
get_usecase_customer
get_kungesId_FY_cusper
fill_missing_products
update_chart_budget_uc1
get_Berein
set_hierarchy
get_element_num_value
icas_dyn_create_chart_table
get_xmlTemplate
...
```

As one can see the "GROUP BY" produces a completely different order.

What I WOULD HAVE WANTED:

```
set_option_value
get_rights_usecase
get_fun_AppOptionsSingleVal
get_rights_usecase
...
```

Basically, what I want can be achieved very simply by taking the text output of

```
  SELECT module FROM logging
  ORDER BY pdate asc
```

and pipe it through "uniq" on the Unix command line. Now I'm just curious why this isn't as simple in SQL.

Comment: The expected answer: [mod1, mod2, mod1, mod3] doesn't quite respond to [select distinct module], as you can see the mod1 is repeating. So actually you don't want a Select Distinct. Do you have a better prepared set of data?

Comment: You are right, "group by" would be a better explanation of what I want. Anyway, this doesn't change the problem.

Comment: So, in order to have a better solution for your problem, please complete the input and then output tables with exactly relevant data. Now it's not clear to me how you want the output data to look. This will help us see if current answers are good or need any other input ;-).

Comment: The examnple I gave is sufficient. Instead of "pdate" you could also use "id", an auto-incremented (sequence.nextval) column. Also see my EDIT.

Comment: Are you looking for the last module within each date range or perhaps every module entry from a distinct day/hour/minute?

Comment: I am looking for the modules IN ORDER without duplicate rows! As I said :) So it does not matter if you give me the first, last, whatever row in a date range - it is the same module (text). I just added the desired output for the example under the EDIT as well, hope that helps.

Comment: @Leigh I'm pretty sure Morre wants them batched in date order where a batch is defined as a group of consecutive rows with the same module - that would fit the results he is saying he wants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is which of the `pdate`s for a `module` do you want to use for ordering purposes?

If you are happy to use the largest, you could use:

```
select module from logging order by max(pdate);
```

--- EDIT

I think I get it now - you probably want something like this:

```
select module
from( select module, 
             sum(module_step) over (order by pdate rows unbounded preceding) 
                 as batch_number, 
             pdate
      from( select module, 
                   case lag(module) over (order by pdate) when module then 0 
                        else 1 end as module_step, 
                   pdate from logging) )
group by module, batch_number
order by batch_number;
```

Comment: No, does not work. I get a completely different order than what I should see. I had already tried that :(

Comment: What order *do* you want to see :)

Comment: As explained in the question. Your idea seems obvious, as I said I tried it myself that way, but it doesn't produce the desired result. This question seems simple but it isn't...

Comment: Ok, you're right, I could have got that from the question - I've edited your question to make it a tiny bit more clear.

Comment: The EDIT: getting closer... I get [set_option_value,get_rights_usecase,set_option_value,get_rights_usecase,get_fun_AppOptionsSingleVal,get_rights_usecase], what it should be see my example result above.

Comment: I must say if it gets even more complicated I feel you should get paid, but unfortunately it's more educational than necessary - I just have to let my brain do the filtering of the superfluous lines ;)... or I use a text-tool, e.g. "awk", or pipe the text result through "uniq" on the command line...

Comment: @Mörre - sorry, `lag` not `lead`. corrected above.

Comment: Works - marked as solution. Too bad this isn't nearly as simple as the Unix text pipe solution...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a variation of a previous question [How to get the MAX row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row)

```
SELECT
    L.Module
FROM
    logging L
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT module, MIN(PDATE) AS MinPDate FROM logging GROUP BY module
    ) C ON L.module = C.module AND C.MinPDate = L.PDate
ORDER BY
    L.PDate
```

**EDIT:** *Have switched to MIN of PDATE as your question uses ORDER BY PDate **ASC**, which would translate to MIN (MAX would translate to **DESC** as it returns that latest first)*

***1:*** You may want to change that to MIN() depending on how you want it ordered
***2:*** This is code that works on SQL Server, I think it'll work on Oracle...

Comment: Result: Error code 904, SQL state 42000: ORA-00904: "C"."PDATE": invalid identifier - but that's because you took "L" for "C" after the join... :) And no, I get a different sequence compared to when I look at the raw data (and let my brain do the filtering/grouping)