# Select a single row from two distinct columns

Tags: sql-server, query

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the MAX row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row)

I need to fetch the "latest" row for certain conditions in my `tkhist1` table. Tickets are bound to `TicketNo` and `LocationID`, and I need to select one row for `DISTINCT` values of both of those columns.

Multiple rows may share the same `TicketNo` and `LocationID` though, they are additionally defined by a UniqueID column. I need to select a single row for each combination of TicketNo and LocationID, `SELECTING` the row with the single highest `UniqueID` value. I do not need Unique ID in my `SELECT` statement.

The following query selects some of the information I need, but it does not only grab one row per `UniqueID`. If a row has different values for `FreightPay` (or any other column) it will be SELECTED as a new row.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [TicketNo],
    [LocationID],   
    [FreightPay]
  FROM [Tkhist1]
```

I need a single row for each distinct pair of `TicketNo` and `LocationID`, selecting only information from the highest value (`DESC`) `UniqueID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `INNER JOIN` on a subquery:

```
SELECT  t1.[TicketNo],
        t1.[LocationID],   
        t1.[FreightPay]
FROM [Tkhist1] t1
INNER JOIN (
                SELECT TicketNo,
                       LocationID,
                       MAX(UniqueID) UniqueID
                FROM Tkhist1
                GROUP BY TicketNo, LocationID
             ) sub
    ON sub.UniqueID = T1.uniqueId
```