# Filter and then sort products by availability

Tags: mysql, mariadb, group-by, order-by

I have table with products. Each product can be avaible in 1+ suppliers, so product can be present multiple times.

```
products
- id_productSupplier (primary key)
- id_product (foreign key)
- availability (int - how many days takes to deliver product)
```

I need:

- list of 10 `product_id`
- 1 record per `id_product` with lowest `availability`
- sort it by `availability` of lowest available `availability` per `product_id`

For example, when `id_productSupplier` has `availability=0`, and other `id_productSupplier` with same `product_id` has `availability=5`, I want to order this `product_id` with `availability=0`.

Data:

```
id_productSupplier | id_product | availability 
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 1 | 5
3 | 2 | 7
4 | 2 | 4
5 | 3 | 1
```

Expected result:

```
id_productSupplier | id_product | availability 
5 | 3 | 1
1 | 1 | 2
4 | 2 | 4
```

Here what I have so far:

```
SELECT id_product FROM products GROUP BY id_product ORDER BY availability LIMIT 10
```

This does not really work, as it first randomly groups id_product and then orders by availability...

So, is there way to first get rid of records with greater `availability` for particular `product_id` and then sort it by `availability`?

I use MariaDB 5.5 (almost same as MySQL 5.5).

Answer (score 0):

This is a ["top n per group"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1004/630) problem but within the limits of MySQL.
You need to GROUP first then join back

```
SELECT 
   F.*
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    MIN(availability) AS MINavailability, id_product
  FROM
    foo
  GROUP BY
    id_product
  ) X
  JOIN
  foo F ON X.id_product = F.id_product AND X.MINavailability = F.availability
ORDER BY
    F.availability, F.id_product
```